# How to generate positional arguments for another function from tkinter entry

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

a beginner coder here. I am trying to make a gui form that gathers data into a sql database and at the same time display it in a treeview.

```
def adddata():
    backend2.adddata(food.get(), transport.get(), insurance.get(), installments.get(), others.get())
```

For the example, you can see that I have 5 entry fields which I need to get data from and pass it onto the database with the adddata function. Imagine if I have to add 5 more fields, and I have 10 of such similar functions, it will be tedious to add them into the code manually.

Therefore is there a way to generate a list of positional arguments to pass into the backend.adddata2() function? Thanks.

Comment: if you have a tuple of your arguments `args`, then you can call `backend2.addata(*args)`

Comment: keep all `Entry` on list then you can use `for` loop to execute `.get()` on every element on list and then you can use new list with `adddata()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

It separates the concern of obtaining the data, and the responsibility of storing it. When you have more data fields to gather and store, only `get_data` will require updating.

```
def get_data():
    food_ = food.get()
    transport_ = transport.get()
    insurance_ = insurance.get()
    installments_ = installments.get()
    others_ = others.get()
    return food_, transport_, insurance_, installments_, others_

def adddata():
    data = get_data()
    backend2.adddata(*data)
```